# Call cleanup as role in ansible using block

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a cleanup call in ansible when something is failed in any of the roles, I have three roles and in case of any failure seen in these three roles call CLEANUP_ROLE.

```
1. ROLE_A
2. ROLE_B
3. ROLE_C
```

and 4th is cleanup role(CLEANUP_ROLE), Following is my main.yml playbook. http://www.yamllint.com/ says that following YML is correct, but I am still getting failures in ansible. Can someone help me to point out where is the error ?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  block:
  roles:
    - {role: ROLE_A}
    - {role: ROLE_B,VAR_A: 3 ,VAR_B: 6 }
  tags:
     - FOOBAR
  rescue:
    - {role: CLEANUP_ROLE}



- hosts: REMOTE_NODES
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  block:
  roles:
    - {role: ROLE_C,VAR_A: 3 ,VAR_B: 6}
  rescue:
    - {role: CLEANUP_ROLE}
```

Following error is coming:

```
ERROR! 'rescue' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/monk/ansible/main.yml': line 10, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: localhost
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following is my main.yml playbook. http://www.yamllint.com/ says that following YML is correct

Well, that depends on how one defines "correct". It may very well be *legal* yaml, in that it is well-formed, but it is not "valid" because it is not indented correctly.

[`rescue:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#block) is only for use within a `block:`, not within a playbook, and thus you probably **meant** to use [`import_role:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/import_role_module.html):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - block:
      - import_role: 
          name: ROLE_A
      - import_role:
          name: ROLE_B
        vars:
          VAR_A: 3
          VAR_B: 6
    rescue:
      - include_role: {role: CLEANUP_ROLE}
    tags:
      - FOOBAR
```

(although be aware that I didn't test whether you can `rescue:` an `import_role:` in that way, it is at least more likely to be functional ansible code than your code snippet)